# Should using the Function constructor form a closure?

Tags: javascript

Functions create a closure in JavaScript.

There are three ways of defining functions in JavaScript: function statement, function expression (named/unnamed) and using the `Function` constructor function.

Should using the Function constructor form a closure?

Comment: No, it doesn't, unless you think of closing over the global scope as a closure.

Comment: Are you asking if it should be the way it is, or what is the actual behavior?

Comment: The way it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. They are always in global context, and are able to access their own variables and obviously the global ones.

[**MDN:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) (Emphasis mine)

> Functions created with the Function constructor **do not create closures
>   to their creation contexts**; they always are created in the global
>   scope. When running them, they will only be able to access their own
>   local variables and global ones, not the ones from the scope in which
>   the Function constructor was called. This is different from using [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)
>   with code for a function expression.